# Select a columns name as another tables row data in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table say `Configs` in which I have the column names

```
id  | Name
-------------
1   | Fruits
2   | Vegetables
3   | Pulses
```

I have another table say `Details`

```
id  |Field1 | Field2| Field3   | Active | Mandatory
-------------------------------------------------
1   |Apple  |Potato |Red gram  |  1     |0
2   |Mango  |Peas   |Chick Peas|  0     |0
```

I need field1, field2, field3 to be selected as the name of 1st table
eg.

```
select 
    id,
    Field1 as Fruits,
    Field2 as Vegetables,
    Field3 as pulses,
    Active,
    Mandatory 
From  
    Details
```

How do I do it?

Comment: Can you elaborate further? Also can you provide more data?

Comment: after "as" clause  i need the row data from "configs" table in the exact same order as the Id from "configs" table .. may i please know what part of the question needs elaboration?

Comment: you would need to use `Dynamic SQL`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
declare @sql    nvarchar(max)

select  @sql    = isnull(@sql + ',' ,'')
        + N'Field' + convert(varchar(10), id) + ' as ' + quotename(Name)
from    Config

-- Form the dynamic SQL
select  @sql    = 'SELECT id,'
        + @sql
        + ',Active, Mandatory '
        + 'FROM Details'

-- Print to verify
print   @sql

-- Execute it
exec    sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: Very Nice solution!

Answer (score 2):

Something like these perhaps:

### Method #1

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'Configs', N'U') IS NULL
    CREATE TABLE Configs(ID INT, Name NVARCHAR(25));
ELSE
    TRUNCATE TABLE Configs

INSERT INTO Configs VALUES(1, 'Fruits'), (2, 'Vegetables'), (3, 'Pulses');

IF OBJECT_ID(N'Configs', N'U') IS NULL
    CREATE TABLE Details(ID INT, Field1 NVARCHAR(25), Field2 NVARCHAR(25), Field3 NVARCHAR(25)
                        ,Active BIT, Mandatory BIT);
ELSE
    TRUNCATE TABLE Details

INSERT INTO Details VALUES(1, 'Apples', 'Potato', 'Red Gram', 1, 0)
                            ,(2, 'Mango', 'Peas', 'Chick Peas', 0, 0);

DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SELECT @Sql = 'SELECT id,' + CHAR(13)
            + ' [Field1] as ' + QUOTENAME((SELECT Name FROM Configs WHERE ID = 1)) +',' + CHAR(13)
            + ' [Field2] as ' + QUOTENAME((SELECT Name FROM Configs WHERE ID = 2)) +',' + CHAR(13)
            + ' [Field3] as ' + QUOTENAME((SELECT Name FROM Configs WHERE ID = 3)) +',' + CHAR(13)
                + ' Active,' + CHAR(13)
                + ' Mandatory ' + CHAR(13)
                + 'From  Details' + CHAR(13);

PRINT @Sql;
EXEC sp_executesql @Sql;
```

### Method #2

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'Configs', N'U') IS NULL
    CREATE TABLE Configs(ID INT, Name NVARCHAR(25));
ELSE
    TRUNCATE TABLE Configs

INSERT INTO Configs VALUES(1, 'Fruits'), (2, 'Vegetables'), (3, 'Pulses');

IF OBJECT_ID(N'Configs', N'U') IS NULL
    CREATE TABLE Details(ID INT, Field1 NVARCHAR(25), Field2 NVARCHAR(25), Field3 NVARCHAR(25)
                        ,Active BIT, Mandatory BIT);
ELSE
    TRUNCATE TABLE Details

INSERT INTO Details VALUES(1, 'Apples', 'Potato', 'Red Gram', 1, 0)
                            ,(2, 'Mango', 'Peas', 'Chick Peas', 0, 0);

DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(9) + 'ID' + CHAR(13);

SELECT
    @Sql += STUFF((
                    SELECT
                        CHAR(9) + ',' + QUOTENAME('Field' + LTRIM(STR(ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY ID)))) + ' AS ' + QUOTENAME(Name) + CHAR(13)
                    FROM
                        Configs
        FOR XML PATH(''), type).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 0, '');

SELECT
    @Sql += CHAR(9) +',Active' + CHAR(13)
            + CHAR(9) +',Mandatory ' + CHAR(13)
            + 'From  Details' + CHAR(13);

PRINT @Sql;
EXEC sp_executesql @Sql;
```